# Attribute tooltips - How can i improve my code?

Tags: php, magento, optimization

I'm working on a site that needs to display various tooltips depending on the product. I'm working with Magento 1.9.0.1 CE. And I'm looking for a way to minimize my code.

My code looks like this:

setting the attributeLabel according to the attribute defined in magento.

```
$attributeLabel1 = $_product->getSpecField1Label();
$attributeLabel2 = $_product->getSpecField2Label();
$attributeLabel3 = $_product->getSpecField3Label();
$attributeLabel4 = $_product->getSpecField4Label();
$attributeLabel5 = $_product->getSpecField5Label();
$attributeLabel6 = $_product->getSpecField6Label();
$attributeLabel7 = $_product->getSpecField7Label();
$attributeLabel8 = $_product->getSpecField8Label();
```

Setting the individual attributes in both Danish and Norwegian. The site runs as a multistore with 2 languages. There are more attributes than these (21 total) but it will give you an idea of how the code works.

```
$TipLyskvalitet = '<div class="tooltipText">Lyskvaliteten er baseret på vores eksperters test og vudering af produktet.</div>';
$TipKvalitet = '<div class="tooltipText">Kvaliteten er baseret på våre eksperters tester og vurdering av produktet.</div>';

$TipErstatter = '<div class="tooltipText">Produktet kan erstatte Tilsvarerende glødepærer/halogen spot  med det viste antal Watt.</div>';
$TipTilsvarer = '<div class="tooltipText">Produktet kan erstatte Tilsvarerende glødepærer/halogen spot med det viste antall Watt.</div>';

$TipBruger = '<div class="tooltipText">Produktet bruger maksimalt det viste antal Watt.</div>';
$TipBruker = '<div class="tooltipText">Produktet bruker maksimalt det viste antall Watt.</div>';

$TipDaempbar = '<div class="tooltipText">Kan produktet dæmpes med en lysdæmper? <ul><li><strong>Ja</strong> = Ja det kan det på de fleste lysdæmpere </li><li><strong>(Ja)</strong> = Ja - med forbehold, læs den fulde produktbeskrivelse for yderligere information.</li><li><strong>Nej</strong> = Dette produkt kan ikke dæmpes.</li></ul></div>';
$TipDimbar = '<div class="tooltipText">Kan produktet dimmes med en dimmer? <ul><li><strong>Ja</strong> = Ja det kan det på de fleste typer dimmere </li><li><strong>(Ja)</strong> = Ja - med forbehold, les den fulle produktbeskrivelsen for ytterligere informasjon.</li><li><strong>NEI</strong> = Dette produkt kan ikke dimmes.</li></ul></div>';
```

The icon used to show the tooltip on hover.

```
$tooltipIcon = '<i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>';
```

Check if the first tooltip contains the danish tooltip or the norwegian or nothing at all. (This is only for the first tooltip - theres a list like this for all of the 11 other attributes)

```
if ($attributeLabel1 == 'Lyskvalitet'):
    $productTooltip1 = $TipLyskvalitet;
elseif ($attributeLabel1 == 'Kvalitet'):
    $productTooltip1 = $TipKvalitet;
else: $productTooltip1 = '';
endif;

if ($attributeLabel2 == 'Lyskvalitet'):
$productTooltip2 = $TipLyskvalitet;
elseif ($attributeLabel2 == 'Kvalitet'):
$productTooltip2 = $TipKvalitet;
else: $productTooltip2 = '';
endif;

if ($attributeLabel3 == 'Lyskvalitet'):
$productTooltip3 = $TipLyskvalitet;
elseif ($attributeLabel3 == 'Kvalitet'):
$productTooltip3 = $TipKvalitet;
else: $productTooltip3 = '';
endif;

if ($attributeLabel4 == 'Lyskvalitet'):
$productTooltip4 = $TipLyskvalitet;
elseif ($attributeLabel4 == 'Kvalitet'):
$productTooltip4 = $TipKvalitet;
else: $productTooltip4 = '';
endif;

if ($attributeLabel5 == 'Lyskvalitet'):
$productTooltip5 = $TipLyskvalitet;
elseif ($attributeLabel5 == 'Kvalitet'):
$productTooltip5 = $TipKvalitet;
else: $productTooltip5 = '';
endif;

if ($attributeLabel6 == 'Lyskvalitet'):
$productTooltip6 = $TipLyskvalitet;
elseif ($attributeLabel6 == 'Kvalitet'):
$productTooltip6 = $TipKvalitet;
else: $productTooltip6 = '';
endif;

if ($attributeLabel7 == 'Lyskvalitet'):
$productTooltip7 = $TipLyskvalitet;
elseif ($attributeLabel7 == 'Kvalitet'):
$productTooltip7 = $TipKvalitet;
else: $productTooltip7 = '';
endif;

if ($attributeLabel8 == 'Lyskvalitet'):
$productTooltip8 = $TipLyskvalitet;
elseif ($attributeLabel8 == 'Kvalitet'):
$productTooltip8 = $TipKvalitet;
else: $productTooltip8 = '';
endif;
```

Showing the end result on the site

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('spec_field1') == ""): ?>

<li style="display: none;"></li>

<?php else: ?>

<li><div class="product-infobox-header-bg"><?php if ($productTooltip1 != ""): echo '<div class="attributeTooltipLabel">' . $attributeLabel1  . $tooltipIcon; else: echo $attributeLabel1 . '<div>'; endif;?><div class="attributeTooltip"><div class="tooltipHeadline"><?php echo $attributeLabel1; ?></div>

<?php echo $productTooltip1; ?>

      </div></div>

      </div><br><?php print $_product->getAttributeText('spec_field1'); ?></li>

<?php endif; ?>
```

So my question is - is there an easier way to do this? The code works but i'm experiencing problems with the server memory and i'm trying to optimize my code.

I am for security purposes not allowed to show you the rest of the code, but i will try and accommodate any requests for snippets.